# WinJS ListView: unable to set property _itemsCount

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I just encountered an error `unable to set property '_itemsCount' of undefined or null reference`. There is no such property anwhere in my code, so I browsed the WinJS source and found that there is in fact a property `_itemsCount` used in the WinJS ListView.

The error didn't reappear, even though I tried reproducing it a number of times. Now I fear I have a Heisenbug lurking somewhere: did anyone encounter this one before? Do you have any tips how to get rid of it?

Update: I looked through the WinJS code a bit and found that `_itemsCount` is probably related to management of the current selection.

Comment: such error are typically seen when a property is dereferenced from a null object. for example - x._itemsCount where is x is null or undefined. do you have list view in your code and do you bind it async in a promise to items? are you exiting the page without cancelling the promise loading the items and setting it to listview?

Comment: The ListView gets its items from an itemDataSource. It will load the items asynchronously but I expect the ListView to cancel any pending promises it created when requesting items from its data source by itself. After all, it wouldn't make much sense to have the datasource keep track of promises it returns and wire these together with navigation - that would just be ugly architecture.

Comment: I was not talking about internal promises of listview. I was referring whether the page .js file have any winjs.xhr promise for example that needs to be cancelled in page unload. again - your code may/may not have the same issue.

Comment: Assuming that the ListView cancels all promises with the data source and the item renderer by itself, there are no other promises in this code that have anything to do with it.

Comment: How is the data source assigned?  One thing I've overlooked several times when binding to a WinJS.Binding.List is that I need to set the data source to "myList.datasource" -- not simply to "myList".  Not on Win8 at the moment so can't test to see if that produces the same error.

Comment: It's a custom datasource, not a WinJS.Binding.List and it's set via databinding (i.e. data-win-bind on the ListView HTML).

Comment: You can reproduce the issue by entering a page where you have a listview that loads a custom datasource and then go back or to another page as fast as possible.